# Kinases that are ATP-sensitive at physiological conditions?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics, kinetics, phosphorylation

Phosphorylation is an ATP-dependent process performed by kinases. At physiological conditions it is generally assumed that ATP concentration is high enough so that ATP is not a limiting factor. Therefore the phosphorylation rate is independent of ATP concentration variations. At least this is the case in the examples I came across.

Are there known counterexample? A kinase that is sensitive to ATP concentration at physiological conditions?

Comment: Yes - AMP-activated protein kinase - or better known as AMPK. This kinase is sensitive to the ATP to AMP ratio with himself – search pubmed for any review on ANP kinase and you'll find more information.

Comment: Great, thanks! I would like to get other examples, I searched the literature with the keywords "ATP-sensitive kinase", or "ATP-regulated kinase" but couldn't find any. Maybe there are better keywords?